# ImageView inside Toolbar is not well positioned on tablets

Tags: android, imageview, toolbar

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYWi9.png)

I have a Toolbar with an ImageView inside. My problem is that this image is not positioned at the center of my Toolbar on tablets(it works fine on mobile devices). What can I do? Gravity doesn't work and I can't use a relative layout. There is an image on top showing my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="mfceo.project.matiasnagore.powerlist.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
    android:background="#fafafa"
    android:titleTextColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="top">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagePowerlist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/powerlist"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="55dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_top"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ffffff">

</FrameLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow"/>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    design:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items"
    design:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
    design:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
    android:background="#FFFAFAFA" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the image here..

Comment: Have you provided layout for the tablet?

Comment: What do you mean? @eenvincible

Comment: The image is on top @srikanth

Comment: @MatiasNagore Eenvincible is asking about, whether.. have you tried placing the same layout for tablet in separate folder, where it can be used only for tablets... so that you can have 2 layouts one is for mobiles and another one is for tablet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal" into your ImageView and remove paddings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="mfceo.project.matiasnagore.powerlist.MainActivity"><android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
    android:background="#fafafa"
    android:titleTextColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="top">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagePowerlist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/powerlist"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_top"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ffffff">

</FrameLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow"/>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    design:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items"
    design:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
    design:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
    android:background="#FFFAFAFA" /></LinearLayout>
```